# Dynamically switching between canvases wpf

Tags: wpf, canvas

I have multiple canvas images of different types (image source, geometry, path) and wish to only show 1 depending on a string binding.

whats the best way to do this?

i'd like it to be reusable so i can place this code inside a user control and then have many of these images around the app and i select which 1 is shown.

Like so:

```
<CanvasImage Image="Pie"/>
<CanvasImage Image="Dog"/>
```

Would it be too computationally expensive to have them all declared in the user control view and use visibility bindings

Pie canvas example:

```
<canvas>
    <Data ="m24,98,07">
</canvas>
```

Dog canvas example:

```
<canvas>
    <image source="">
<canvas>
```

Comment: please can you show some sample code

Comment: I've read this this question now 3 times and still have no clue of what you're asking. Is it about reusability? Performance? How to bind something?

Comment: basically i have now a user control called CanvasImage. inside that i have many images all in a canvas each.

i bind each canvas visibility and turn them all off except the 1 i require. i then reuse this user control over and over again only turning on 1 image each time. almost like how a font works

is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This sounds like, a `ResourceDictionary` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This converter return an image source directly, depending on the value it receives.

```
namespace TestTreeView.Views
{
    public class StringToImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string file = "";

            string v = value as string;
            switch (v)
            {
                case "Pie":
                    file = @".\path\to\your\pie.jpg";
                    break;
                case "Dog":
                    file = @".\path\to\your\dog.jpg";
                    break;
                default:
                    return null;
            }

            return new BitmapImage(new Uri(file, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage in XAML:

```
<Window xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace.Views" ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:StringToImageConverter x:Key="stringToImageConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Canvas>
            <Image Source="{Binding YourString, Converter={StaticResource stringToImageConverter}}"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

*Original answer*

I think you need to use a Converter.
It will take a ConverterParameter, a String, that will tell what the binded value is expected to be, and return a Visiblity to indicate if the canvas should be visible or not.

```
namespace YourNamespace.Views
{
    public class StringToCanvasVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string v = value as string;
            string p = parameter as string;
            return (v != null && p != null && v == p) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage in XAML:

```
<Window xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace.Views" ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:StringToVisibilityConverter x:Key="stringToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Canvas Visibility="{Binding YourString, Converter={StaticResource stringToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=Pie}"/>
        <Canvas Visibility="{Binding YourString, Converter={StaticResource stringToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=Dog}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```